# Memory management. Byte copy of CF Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have come across an interesting question.

I have this piece of code (don't ask why I need to do something like this):

```
CFDataRef data = ... get data from somewhere
SSLContextRef sslContext;
CFDataGetBytes(data, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(SSLContextRef)), (UInt8 *)&sslContext);
```

Now I don't know what to do with `sslContext`. As I understand I have made a byte copy of SSLContextRef and I need to free that memory after I used it.

So here comes a question: how can I properly free memory?

Again as I understand I can't do CFRelease because I didn't increment reference count when I got(copied) the object and if I simply try to do `free(sslContext)` I get crash.

I would appreciate if someone could explain how it should work.

> 

EDIT: Thanks to user **gaige**. He has pointed that in the question I have copied only reference to SSLContextRef. As I understand if I do:

```
UInt8 *buffer = malloc(sizeof(SSLContext));
CFDataGetBytes(data, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(SSLContext)), buffer);
```

I then I can just do `free(buffer);` without any problem (provided that I didn't do any CFRetain/CFRelease logic). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you copied `sizeof(SSLContextRef)` bytes of data from the `CFDataRef` pointed at by `data`, you didn't increase any reference counts, nor did you copy any data other than the pointer to the `SSLContext` structure.   (`SSLContextRef` is declared as a pointer to `struct SSLContext`).

The data you copied ended up in `sslContext` in your current stack frame, and thus doesn't need any special curation by you in order to make it go away.

In short, you don't need to do anything because no data was copied in the heap.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've just missed that I have copied only pointer. I will update my question.